# How to set up oscommerce Shipping to these settings?

Tags: oscommerce

I need to set it up so that it is:

- $4.95 flat rate for anywhere in US.
- $11.95 for anywhere else in North America.
- $13.95 for anywhere else in the world.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the multi geozone multi table shipping mod.

http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/2571

If you prefer, you could clone the build-in zones mod twice, and apply the original to the US, the first clone to Canada/Mexico and the second clone to everywhere else.